# Getting `The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 5` when using Gtihub Actions to deploy with SFTP. Anyone know what this means?

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to push files to a remote host via SFTP with Github Actions.

When I run a push command the action does fire but I get the error:

> The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 5

My Action is as such:

```
on: push
name: Publish Website
jobs:
  FTP-Deploy-Action:
    name: FTP-Deploy-Action
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2.1.0
      with:
        fetch-depth: 2
    - name: FTP-Deploy-Action
      uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@3.1.1
      with:
        ftp-server: sftp.mysite.com/httpdocs/assets/themes
        ftp-username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
        ftp-password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
        git-ftp-args: --insecure
```

Would anyone know what this could be from and how to fix?

(also, would anyone know where I should be placing the port number?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I had to update the `ftp-server` value by adding the protocol (sftp://) and port number (22). So:

`ftp-server: sftp://sftp.mysite.com:22/httpdocs/assets/themes`

Answer (score 0):

Use This code its latest updted  and working fine

```
  on: push
   name:  Deploy website on push
   jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name:  Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name:  Get latest code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name:  Sync files
      uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.3.0
      with:
         server: ${{ secrets.FTP_SERVER }}
         username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
         password: ${{ secrets.ftp_password }}
         protocol: ftps
         port: 1234 # todo replace with your web hosts ftps port
```

Read the complete documentation here https://github.com/SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are setting wrong FTP_SERVER address in your FTP_SERVER secret. Please goto your FTP account in your CPanel (or any other hosting/FTP provider you are using) and check the FTP server address. In my case my address was ftp.mywebsite.net